# Teeth Shifting / Dental Drifting resulting from a Maxillary-first-molar extraction?

Tags: oral-health

If a Maxillary-first-molar is removed from a mouth where all the other teeth are present and OK, how soon would the adjoining molar and tooth start Shifting / Drifting into the empty gap ( causing a Malocclusion ) for someone just over 50 ?

- Also, although the Shifting / Drifting in the above question is an unwanted result of the Maxillary-first-molar extraction, I found a webpage ( maybe only for child age patients ) showing that the Shifting / Drifting can be used intentionally by a dentist to push the Maxillary-second-molar into the empty gap left by the extracted Maxillary-first-molar, however what about the molar behind the Maxillary-second-molar...........

Comment: You are obviously looking for medical advice, which we can't supply on this site - see the banner on the front page and on the right of this page (box above "featured on meta"). This will be closed. Go and see your dentist and/or orthodontist.